# Eager loading single many-to-many relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I have two models connected via a pivot table with an extra column to track the quantity

```
class Item extends Eloquent {
    public function containers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Container', 'items_containers', 'item_id', 'container_id')->withPivot(['quantity']);
    }
}

class Container extends Eloquent { 
    public function items() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'items_containers', 'container_id', 'item_id')->withPivot(['quantity']);
    }
}
```

And a third model for my orders:

```
class OrderItem extends Eloquent {
    public function originalItem()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Item', 'id', 'item_id');
    }
    public function container() {
        return $this->hasOne('Container', 'id', 'container_id');
    }

}
```

What I want is to be able to get the specific data from the pivot table when eager loading the OrderItem models, so I only get the quantity where the `item_id` and `container_id` matches what's on the order item.

```
OrderItems::whereOrderId($orderId)
   ->with(['originalItem', 'container', '???'])
   ->get();
```

What's the best way to specify the relationship on the OrderItem, or load it in with `with`?

Comment: I don't really understand your structure, sorry if I misunderstood. The eloquent way to join models is something like this.
$orderItem = OrderItems::find($orderId);
$orderItem->originalItem;
$orderItem->container;

Comment: The main purpose of using the with command is that I'm returning the data to an angularjs app. I can get the original item and container all day long, but I need to get the specific quantity value that lives in the items_containers pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following returns what you want:

```
$orders = \App\OrderItem::select('item_orders.*', 'items_containers.quantity as quantity')->with('item', 'container')
    ->leftJoin('items_containers', function ($join) {
        $join->on('items_containers.item_id', 'item_orders.item_id')
            ->where('items_containers.container_id', \DB::raw('item_orders.container_id'));
    })
    ->get();
```

Then you can easily get the quantity.

```
$orders->first()->quantity;
```

That's it.

Comment: Of course, attributes! I keep forgetting about that. I'll try this out and let you know.

Comment: It didn't quite get me there, but it definitely got me on the right track. Part of the key was being able to autoload it so I could pass it back in a json response, hence the `with` keywords.

Comment: I see. You need to have quantity to be part of OrderItem collection.

Answer (score 1):

Major props to Morteza Rajabi for getting me on the right track. The first key was getting the specific relation, since while Items and Containers are a Many-to-Many relationship, the OrderItem has a One-to-One relationship with both the Item and the Container. In order to get the specific relationship quantity, I had to create an attribute specifying it:

```
public function getItemContainerQtyAttribute() {
    if($this->item_id && $this->container_id) {
        return $this->depoItem->containers()->where('items_containers.container_id', $this->container_id)->first()->pivot->quantity;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The item_id and container_id check is because this is a work in progress, and the OrderItems haven't always been created correctly, and some items don't have a container specified.

The next step was to autoload it with the `appends` attribute within Eloquent:

```
protected $appends = ['item_container_qty'];
```

Now whenever I load `$item = OrderItems::whereOrderId($order_id)->get();`, it will load the the pivot quantity automatically.

Comment: It does the job, But it's not efficient. It will make N+3 queries for N orders.

Comment: Your right, and jsonSerialize is balking at it. I'm going to have to tweak this some more.

Comment: Why don't you use joins?

Comment: *headdesk* Because I like to make things difficult? Or, rather, I was thinking more along the lines of Eloquent instead of simple sql. That did it, all I had to do was remember to tell it to get the column(s) from the `items_containers` as well. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean :). You don't wanna use it, or you forgot about query builder?

Comment: I mean I forgot. I've been so focused on doing everything with Eloquent relationships that I completely forgot that sometimes joins are quicker and easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155105/discussion-between-morteza-rajabi-and-aynber).